# Storing multiple image paths in one column of MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm able to upload multiple images to the upload folder and its path to the database but my code is **creating new row in database for each image with new id (which i dont want)**. I want to store all the images path to a single column in database with same id and separated with comma.

here is my php code:

```
    <?php
    include('connection.php');
    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {

    $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $explode = explode('.', $name);


    $ext = end($explode);

    $path = 'uploads/';
    $path = $path . basename( $explode[0] . time() .'.'. $ext);

     $sql="INSERT into pictures (FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE ) 
     VALUES('$name','$size','$type'); ";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $errors = array();

    if(empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please choose at least 1 file to be uploaded.';
    }else {

        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','bmp','png');

        $max_size = 2000000; // 2MB

        if(in_array($ext, $allowed) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> extension is not allowed.';
        }

        if($size > $max_size) {
            $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> size is too hight.';
        }

    }

    if(empty($errors)) {

        if(!file_exists('uploads')) {
            mkdir('uploads', 0777);
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {
            echo '<p>The file <b>'.$name.'</b> successful upload</p>';
        }else {
            echo 'Something went wrong while uploading 
     <b>'.$name.'</b>';
        }

    }else {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p>'.$error.'<p>';
        }
    }

}

    ?>
```

database screenshot as below

[image]

Comment: Where are you inserting path, i do not see any $path variable in your query

Comment: @Narayan: I approved your edit suggestion because of the image, but I don't think there was any need to indent the code again.

Comment: _"but my code is creating new row in database for each image with new id (which i dont want)"_ - you _should_ want this; it is called proper normalization. Comma-separated values are going to cause you trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just improve your code and also place insert query outside the foreach loop

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$files = [];
foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {

    $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $explode = explode('.', $name);


    $ext = end($explode);

    $updatdName = $explode[0] . time() .'.'. $ext;
    $path = 'uploads/';
    $path = $path . basename( $updatdName );

    if(empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please choose at least 1 file to be uploaded.';
    }else {

        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','bmp','png');

        $max_size = 2000000; // 2MB

        if(in_array($ext, $allowed) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> extension is not allowed.';
        }

        if($size > $max_size) {
            $errors[] = 'The file <b>'.$name.'</b> size is too hight.';
        }

    }

    if(empty($errors)) {

        // if there is no error then set values
        $files['file_name'][] = $updatdName;
        $files['size'][] = $size;
        $files['type'][] = $type;
        $errors = array();
        if(!file_exists('uploads')) {
            mkdir('uploads', 0777);
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {
            echo '<p>The file <b>'.$name.'</b> successful upload</p>';
        }else {
            echo 'Something went wrong while uploading 
     <b>'.$name.'</b>';
        }

    }else {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p>'.$error.'<p>';
        }
    }

}

if(!empty($files)) {

    $files['file_name'][] = $updatdName;
    $files['size'][] = $size;
    $files['type'][] = $type;
    $names = implode(',', $files['file_name']);
    $sizes = implode(',', $files['size']);
    $types = implode(',', $files['type']);
    $sql="INSERT into pictures (FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE ) 
         VALUES('$names','$sizes','$types'); ";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming you have a form with an input field named 'product_images[]' for multiple file uploads

// Get the uploaded files
$uploadedFiles = $_FILES['images'];

// Array to store the uploaded file names
$imageNames = [];

// Loop through each uploaded file
foreach ($uploadedFiles['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName) {
    // Generate a unique file name or use the original file name
    $imageName = uniqid() . '_' . $uploadedFiles['name'][$key];

    // Move the uploaded file to a directory
    $destination = 'path/to/your/upload/directory/' . $imageName;
    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $destination);

    // Add the file name to the array
    $imageNames[] = $imageName;
}

// Save the image names in the database
$commaSeparatedImageNames = implode(',', $imageNames);

// Assuming you have a database connection established
$query = "INSERT INTO products (image_names) VALUES ( '$commaSeparatedImageNames')";
// Execute the query to insert the product details into the database
// Remember to use prepared statements or sanitize the input to prevent SQL injection
```